# Slow queries on idle server

Tags: mysql

I have a development MySQL server running on a dedicated CentOS virtual machine, under VirtualBox & Windows.

I've been using it for months with a pretty decent performance, and have an history of SQL patches to create a project's database from scratch that up to now, was taking less than a minute to run.

When I tried to re-run the patches today, it started to take several minutes, which is considerably slower than it used to be.

Here is a `top` output when it looks the most "busy":

[image: top output]

But most of the time, the output is the following:

[image: top output]

`mysqladmin status` says:

```
Uptime: 805  Threads: 3  Questions: 894  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 1277
Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 98  Queries per second avg: 1.110
```

So, for me, the server looks almost idle, although it's actually running a big SQL patch, and making me wait for ages...

Any idea what could be slowing it down?

Comment: Is it possible that your shared disk is having IO/disk issues or is Busy? Seeing that you are running a virtual host on your Windows PC.

Comment: I just found the reason (see below). Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the reason.
The queries themselves weren't slow, but the connection to the MySQL server was.
And because the `mysql` command-line was executed once for each patch, that made it painfully slow.

I added the following line to `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
skip-name-resolve
```

And everything's back to normal!

Comment: You may want to add `skip-host-cache` as well : See my DBA StackExchange post http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7122/877

Comment: @Rolando What does `skip-host-cache` do when the name resolution is disabled?

Comment: `--skip-host-cache` disables internal host cache for faster name-to-IP resolution. In this case, the server performs a DNS lookup every time a client connects.

Comment: I thought that `skip-name-resolve` would prevent ip-to-name resolution, and that because a cache would make sense only when name resolution is On, `skip-host-cache` would be useless (ineffective) in this case?

Comment: I usually recommend both be used anyway.